# How to download only .exe files from a website using wget?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, mirroring

I want to download only .exe files from example.com , I used wget -mk http://example.com / but it downloads all files of the website .. also I want to avoid some folders like /fr , /jp from the website . 
How to do that ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to download all exe's use *

```
wget http://example.com/*.exe
```

Comment: and to exclude dirs use:
`--exclude-directories=LIST  list of excluded directories.`

Comment: There's no way this is going to work; the shell will look for files that match `"http://example.com/*.exe"` in the current directory and almost certainly fail horribly.